# How to connect Algosec and servicenow?

Tags: content-management-system, servicenow

My query is where do I write the script to connect both the platforms from algosec side and how do I configure the algosec platform to execute that script automatically when an event occurs(insert,update).

I tried to follow [this link](https://www.algosec.com/docs/en/asms/a30.00/asms-help/content/ff-config-guide/integrating-fireflow-via-a.htm) and executed the command in the third step but it always throws an error :

`wsdl2perl.pl command not found`

Can someone provide a step by step walkthrough for this?